# Convert SQL Server recursive WITH clause to Oracle 10g

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle10g

I have problem with this query

```
DECLARE @INPUT INT
SET     @INPUT = 12345

;
WITH ABCD(SEQ, X, Y)
AS
(
    SELECT  1, 
            @INPUT % 10,
            @INPUT / 10

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  SEQ + 1,
            Y % 10,
            Y / 10
    FROM    ABCD
    WHERE   X > 0 OR Y > 0
)
SELECT *
FROM   ABCD
ORDER BY SEQ
```

this query will produce something like this

[image]

I want to convert this to Oracle 10g (must valid for 10g)

Thank you

Comment: Oracle didn't get recursive WITH support until 11gR2; you have to use Oracle's native hierarchical/recursive syntax: `CONNECT BY`

Comment: it's OK as long as the result are same :) thank you for your response :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I'm cheating a bit to compute X by relying on string parsing rather than the mathematical operations.</strike>  But something like this appears to work

EDIT: Forgot about the 6th row.  I also removed the character string cheat

```
with t as (
  select 12345 col1 from dual
)
select level seq, 
       trunc((col1 - 
              power(10,level) * trunc(col1/(power(10,level)))) / 
             power(10,level-1)) x,
       trunc(col1/(power(10,level))) y 
  from t
 connect by level <= length(col1)+1
/

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with t as (
  2    select 12345 col1 from dual
  3  )
  4  select level seq,
  5         trunc((col1 -
  6                power(10,level) * trunc(col1/(power(10,level)))) /
  7               power(10,level-1)) x,
  8         trunc(col1/(power(10,level))) y
  9    from t
 10*  connect by level <= length(col1)+1
SQL> /

       SEQ          X          Y
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          5       1234
         2          4        123
         3          3         12
         4          2          1
         5          1          0
         6          0          0

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: thank you for your response :) +1 for your answer. but, where is the 6th level / sequence?

Comment: @tsurahman - Fixed the issue with the 6th issue and with the string cheat.